# Do oscilloscope have a lifetime?

Tags: electronics

The electron gun in an oscilloscope is, from what I understand, analogous to the one of a Cathode Ray tube. It is made of a material that emits electrons via thermionic emission.

Doesn't this slowly wear out the gun? Should it be replaced at some point? Do oscilloscopes have a finite lifetime then?

Comment: Yes, crt's will fail eventually. The old ones were built like tanks, though. And most of my scopes are LCDs now anyway...

Comment: Just like any other CRT it will gradually dim over time. But unlike old CRT TV's, I don't think that oscilloscopes are usually left on for hours at a time (although there are exceptions). You'll probably want to get a new, digital oscilloscope anyway by the time the CRT wears out.

Comment: A digital oscilloscope doesn't have a CRT? What's the electron gun?

Comment: And by the way what's heating the electron gun? Power from the mains?

Comment: @SuperCiocia: "A digital oscilloscope doesn't have a CRT?" - LOL! Are you kidding? All the ones I've seen have gone to LCD screens long ago. The youngest piece of equipment I have with a CRT is an SRS850 lock-in amp with like a 5" screen (http://www.thinksrs.com/products/SR850.htm) which is about 15 years old, I think. Still works fine but the newer lock-ins have gone to LCD screens.

Comment: Correction: Excuse me, it looks like the SRS850 lock-in with the CRT is still being sold. Pretty surprising. There is a newer model lock-in with a color LCD display, but the older CRT model still is being sold. We thought that the CRT display was a bit dated and behind the times even back about 15 years ago when we bought our SRS850 lock-in.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: *"What's the electron gun?"* An electron gun is an implementation detail (albeit one that was universal for a long time), *not* a requisite part of an oscilloscope.

Comment: OK, thanks. So what's the source of electrons in new oscilloscopes?

Comment: @SuperCiocia "Source of electrons in new oscilloscopes" - you mean "source of light" I suppose. Most have a liquid crystal display - "any" light source (usually either cold cathode fluorescence, or LED) behind a screen whose transparency is adjusted electronically (by leveraging the property of liquid crystals to twist a polarized signal depending on their electrical state).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, oscilloscopes will eventually wear out. They last a long time, if they are taken care of. There are many vintage scopes out there that are 30+ years old that still work perfectly. Here are a few examples of failure modes. There are probably more. 1.) Phosphor coating on the inside of the tube wears out, causing the display to dim. 2.) The tube develops a crack or otherwise leaks atmosphere to the inside, causing the CRT to stop working. 3.) Components drift out of spec as they age, causing the scope to become inaccurate. 4.) The electronics fail. This could be from old electrolytic caps, mechanical stress, broken solder joints, worn out or broken vacuum tubes, corrosion of board-to-board connectors, exposure of insulation to ultraviolet light. 4.) Scopes can also break from abuse or wear and tear. Drops, spills, over voltages, power surges, etc. can all break a scope.